# RoR Rake Test Failure: expecting <"users/show"> but rendering with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running a integration test in Rails 4, and I am receiving the following failure:

```
1) Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_valid_signup_information [/Users/************/workspace/myapp/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:38]:
expecting <"users/show"> but rendering with <["shared/_error_messages", "users/new", "layouts/_header", "layouts/_footer", "layouts/application", "user_mailer/account_activation", "static_pages/home"]>

22 runs, 120 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The test that it is pointing to is here:

```
 test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                                            email: "user@example.com",
                                            password:              "password",
                                            password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

In the users controller, the create function is here:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver!
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Do you see what is wrong here, and why the failure is throwing?  Thank you.

EDIT:

logfile for the UsersLoginTest: test_valid_signup_information:

```
UsersLoginTest: test_valid_signup_information
---------------------------------------------
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 762146111 LIMIT 1[0m
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-21 14:03:04 -0800
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.slim (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-21 14:03:04 -0800
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"Example User", "email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `users` (`activation_digest`, `created_at`, `email`, `name`, `password_digest`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('$2a$04$DEMdkJmbjK3DUTmv7O2u7eX6Cy7nfYErvEoO4fN62vMGZ5XDwyrnC', '2015-01-21 22:03:04', 'user@example.com', 'Example User', '$2a$04$1L56dTrE0Wa./qUOhzA50OKako81UG3wO25Z00Dj2UkejeW1e6hQi', '2015-01-21 22:03:04')[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 5.8ms
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-21 14:03:04 -0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`[0m
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It looks like the line `@user.save` is failing. Is there anything in the logs that would explain why it didn't save?

Comment: To add to Shawn Bush's comment - Some things to look for: Is there a user with that email in your test database that might be conflicting? Possibly from a `before(:each)` (or whatever the `Test::Unit` equivalent is). Is `password` a valid password?

Comment: I added the log output for the test that the failure occurred in.  Do you notice anything off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to root:

```
redirect_to root_url
```

But your test is expecting 'users/show'.

EDIT:
To redirect to user profile:

```
redirect_to @user
```

Comment: In the example I'm using it has the redirect to the root_url in the create function.  What exactly do I need to change, if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: Well, you never stated what the expected behavior is. Are you doing TDD and trying to get the app the match the test? Or do you want to change the test, as the app behavior is correct?

Comment: I am simply trying to have user authentication functionality put into the site.  I guess I don't know why there is a disconnect here

Comment: Is the expected behavior to redirect to **root_url** or **users#show** after the sign up?

Comment: After they signup or login with correct credentials, it should take them to users#show (their profile).  I think the redirect to root_url should take them to their profile if they are logged in, as I have a filter set up where if you are signed in and you got the main page, you are redirected to your profile.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Now I'm getting the failure: UsersLoginTest#test_valid_signup_information [/Users/*************/workspace/myapp/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:39]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

Comment: ... are you following some sort of tutorial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69357/discussion-between-user1072337-and-tachyonflux).